# DOM throwing error because of Multiple HTML files

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

I am trying to create a simple recipe-app with javascript.
I have 3 HTML files: index.html, create.html, edit.html
and 2 JS files.

I have a couple of DOM elements. One on index.html, Two on edit, Two on create.
Now when I open index.html I get an error:

```
recipe.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
```

The problem here is that the code that the error is it's about edit.html not index.html.
Same problem on edit.html

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
at recipe.js:55
```

recipe.js code 55 is about index.html, not edit.html.

Is there a way to target an HTML file when using DOM.

```
document.getElementById("edit-body").value = getRecipeBody();
```

I want the code above to be only for edit.html, not for index.html or create.html.

## edit-body is a form that is only on edit.html, not on index or create.html

```
document.getElementById('recipes').appendChild(recipeEl)
```

I want this code to be for index.html not for other HTML files because there is no #recipes ID on those files. The #recipes is only on index.html

I am using localStorage.

Comment: Basic null checking? `if (document.getElementById("edit-body") != null) document.getElementById("edit-body").value = getRecipeBody();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[window.location.pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/pathname) would let you execute code for a specific path.

```
if(window.location.pathname === '/edit.html') {
  document.getElementById("edit-body").value = getRecipeBody();
}
```

Note that if you load `index.html` by default (as in, http://localhost:80/ as opposed to http://localhost:80/index.html), then the pathname will simply be `/`, so make sure you handle both of those, i.e.:

```
if(window.location.pathname === '/index.html' || window.location.pathname === '/') {
  document.getElementById('recipes').appendChild(recipeEl)
}
```

A better approach would be to code it defensively. Check that the element you're getting exists before running a function against it. For example:

```
var editEl = document.getElementById("edit-body");
if (editEl) {
  editEl.value = getRecipeBody();
}
```

Instead of either of these, you could also just load `index.js` on `index.html`, `edit.js` on `edit.html`, etc., though you'd want to split out any shared functions into a separate (common) JS file.